# get joint combinations across arrays - python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I efficiently get the joint combinations of `[row,column]` across several index arrays?

For example,

```
A1 = np.array([[0,400],[0,0],[200,0]])
A2 = np.array([[0,0],[188,155],[22,0]])

a1 = A1.nonzero()
a2 = A2.nonzero()
```

`a1` are the indices of `A1`: `[0,1], [2,0]`. `a2` are the indices of `A2`:`[1,0], [1,1], [2,0]`.

given these two arrays, the unique indices are:

```
[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [2,0]
```

or

```
 (np.array([0,1,1,2],
  np.array([1,0,1,0]])
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear. These arrays aren't 2D, and I don't know what you mean by "index arrays". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @emremrah, a1 and a2 are the result of np.nonzero() so they are arrays containing indices of non-zeros

Comment: It's very unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain the logic you are trying to apply here? Also, please post whatever code you already have and let us know what is going wrong so we could try and help

Comment: also, you say that `for a1 the indices are [0,1], [2,0]` but there is no index 2 for `a1` (last index is 1)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. @ExtraFishness I mean that a1 is pointing at the indices of another array. I updated the question, does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
a1 = (np.array([0, 2]), np.array([1, 0]))
a2 = (np.array([1, 1, 2]), np.array([0, 1, 0]))

a1z = set(zip(*a1))
a2z = set(zip(*a2))
res = a1z.union(a2z)
print(res)
```

output:

```
{(0, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```py
a1 = (np.array([0,2]),np.array([1,0]))
a2 = (np.array([1,1,2]),np.array([0,1,0]))

np.unique(np.vstack((np.stack(a1).T, np.stack(a2).T)), axis=0)  # axis=1 could be used instead of .T
```

Outputs:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well your problem, here is what I would do:
1.Transform your indexes arrays of rows and columns in actual 2D array.

```
    a1 = np.concatenate((a1[0].reshape(-1,1), a1[1].reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)
    a2 = np.concatenate((a2[0].reshape(-1,1), a2[1].reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)
```

In your case the output is the following:

```
    >>> a1
    array([[0, 1],
           [2, 0]])
    >>> a2
    array([[1, 0],
           [1, 1],
           [2, 0]])
```

2.Concatenate the resulting arrays together.

```
    a = np.concatenate((a1, a2))
    >>> a
    array([[0, 1],
           [2, 0],
           [1, 0],
           [1, 1],
           [2, 0]])
```

3.Find the unique rows.

```
    np.unique(a, axis=0)
    array([[0, 1],
           [1, 0],
           [1, 1],
           [2, 0]])
```